# Argument 'MyController' is not a function, got undefined: differences between Edge browser and Firefox / Chrome on Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, firefox, microsoft-edge

I am learning AngularJS following the code samples in ng-book.

I have the following folder structure under the app root folder

```
../css
../img
../lib
../lib/angular
../js
../partials
```

I have angular 1.2.11 installed in the lib/angular directory (yes I know this is not the latest version..)

The following code works fine in Firefox (41.0.1) but in Chrome (45.0.2454.101 m), Edge and IE (11.0.22) I get an error message
"Argument 'MyController' is not a function, got undefined"

Code follows:

index.html in root folder:

```
<!doctype html>
    <html lang="en" ng-app>
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>My AngularJS App</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css"/>
    </head>
    <body>
       <div>
           {{1+1}}
       </div>
        <div ng-controller="MyController">
            {{name}}<br/> {{clock}}
        </div>

      <script src="lib/angular/angular.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
     </body>
    </html>
```

in app.js in the js folder:

```
function MyController($scope) {
    $scope.name = "in sub";
    $scope.clock = new Date();
    console.log = "Active";
    var updateClock = function () {
        $scope.clock = new Date();
    };

    setInterval(function () {
        $scope.$apply(updateClock);
    }, 1000);

    updateClock();
};
```

If I put the app.js into the root folder it still does not work so it is not path related.
If I put the code into an inline script then it works so I don't think it is an issue with the code.  Why does this work in one browser but not the others.  For reference i am calling this directly from the file browser, not via http.
file:///C:/Users/aaron_000/Desktop/Programming/Angular/app/index.html
If I upgrade to a later version of angular does the problem go away?
I know that this is not the 'proper' way to construct an Angular app, but I am taking it one component at a time :)

Comment: In upgrades , support for global functions for controllers is removed. Use `http` to load page. There are numerous ways to get a local server running on your machine

Answer (score 0):

Look js/app.js is right. Works fine for me.

```js
var app = angular.module("App", []);

app.controller('AppController', function MyController($scope) {
  $scope.name = "in sub";
  $scope.clock = new Date();
  console.log = "Active";
  var updateClock = function() {
    $scope.clock = new Date();
  };

  setInterval(function() {
    $scope.$apply(updateClock);
  }, 1000);

  updateClock();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.11/angular.min.js"></script>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="App">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>My AngularJS App</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    {{1+1}}
  </div>
  <div ng-controller="AppController">
    {{name}}
    <br/>{{clock}}
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Tried swapping my local angular for the CDN with same result. Which browser did you use.  My point is that it works in FF41 but not in IE11, Edge, or Chrome44 and I would like to know why it works in one but not the others as this adds to the complexity of testing.